# populate 2nd listbox from 1st

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying various codes to populate a 2nd listbox (#box2) but to no avail. My latest attempt is that the JS is not showing anything on change so there must be an error in my code, but I cannot see it. I would be grateful if someone could check my code and show me where I have gone wrong. Many thanks

```
<?php

<select name="box1[]" id="box1" size="7" multiple="multiple" />

<?php
$i = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row["custref"]; ?>">
 <?php echo $row["custref"]; ?></option>
<?php
    $i++;
    }

?>
<select name="box2[]" id="box2" size="7" multiple="multiple" />

<script type="text/javascript">


    $('#box1').change(function()
    {

        var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();

        $('#box2').val(option);

    });

    </script>
```

Comment: `var option = $(this).find('option:selected');`

Comment: are you want to copy first list box to second list box ?

Comment: @Abanoub I need to retrieve the selected items from box1 and insert into box2. thanks

Comment: @dfsq still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code it will append the selected option from Box1 to Box2

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#box1').change(function()
    {
     $box1_value=$("#box1").val();
     $box1_text=$("#box1 option:selected").text();
     $("#box2").append('<option value="'+$box1_value+'">'+$box1_text+'</option>');
}
</script>
```

Comment: It works but I need to remove the selected item from box1 and allow for multiple items. also would it be possible to do it from button click event? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Find selected, clone, append:

```
$('#box1').change(function() {
  var option = $(this).find('option:selected').clone();
  $('#box2').append(option);
});
```